# eigenvalues negative realparts one zero eigenvalue convergence

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

this is a question that arose in my mind as I studied Perko's *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems*.  My intuition says that given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with exactly one zero eigenvalue and such that the real parts of every other eigenvalue of $A$ are negative that the dynamical system $x'=Ax$ should converge to some multiple of the eigenvector associated to 0 as the null space of A is spanned by this vector and is one dimensional.  I am having trouble proving this fact could anyone point me in the right direction?  I have leveraged the Fundamental Theorem to represent the solution to the above system as:

$$
x = Pdiag[B_{j}]P^{-1}[I+N+...+\frac{N^{k-1}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}]x_{0}
$$

For some change of base matrix P where N is a nilpotent matrix of order $k$ and if $a_{j} = Re(\lambda_{j})$ then

$$
B_{j} = \begin{cases}e^{a_{j}t}\begin{bmatrix} cos(b_{j}t)& -sin(b_{j}t) \\ sin(b_{j}t)& cos(b_{j}t)\\        \end{bmatrix} &\text{if $\lambda_{j}$ is complex}\\ 
e^{a_{j}t} &\text{otherwise}\\ \end{cases}            
$$

Not sure where to go next.  Any hints?

Comment: you practically finished. what happens when $t$ goes to infinite?

Comment: I see that every coordinate of my solution is essentially linear combinations of exponentials and polynomials, so I should converge to some nonzero vector as the exponential terms will dominate as t approaches infinity and I will be left with only the terms involving the zero eigenvalue.  What I am having trouble seeing is that the thing I converge to lies in the subspace spanned by the zero eigenvector.

Comment: $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ uniquely decomposes as $v_1 + v_2$, where $v_1$ belongs to the invariant subspace corresponding to the zero eigenvalue and $v_2$ belongs to the sum of the invariant subspaces corresponding to the remaining eigenvalues.  One has that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is $c_1 > 0$ such that $\lVert e^{At} v_1 \rVert \ge c_1 e^{-\epsilon t}$ for $t \ge 0$, and  there is $c_2 > 0$ such that $\lVert e^{At} v_2 \rVert \le c_2 e^{(\mu +\epsilon) t}$ for $t \ge 0$, where $\mu (< 0)$ is the largest real part of the remaining eigenvalues.

Comment: Indeed, under your assumptions ($0$ is a simple eigenvalue) one has even that $\lVert e^{At} v_1 \rVert$ is constant.  Now, after some manipulation one gets that $\lVert e^{At} v_2 \rVert/\lVert e^{At} v_1 \rVert $ converges exponentially to zero (provided that $v_1 \ne 0$), which is just what you need.

Comment: Thank you - I was neglecting to write the vector $P^{-1}[I+N+...+\frac{N^{k-1}t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}]x_{0}$ with respect to the basis given by the generalized eigenvectors of $A$ (in which the zero eigenvector of $A$ is crucially included as 0 is simple). Edit:grammar