# How fast does a solution approach an equilibrium?

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I have an autonomous dynamical system $\dot{\mathbf x}(t)=\mathbf f(\mathbf x(t))$ on $\mathbb R^2$, and I found that solutions are future asymptotic to an equilibrium point $\mathbf a$, i.e.

$\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbf x(t)=\mathbf a$

for all initial conditions in the domain of interest.

I am now interested in how fast solutions approach this equilibrium point, i.e. I would like to obtain an asymptotic expansion (EDIT: valid for large $t$) of the form

$\mathbf x(t)\simeq\mathbf a+(\text{term decaying with $t$})+\dots$.

How can I determine the decaying term, and is the procedure different for hyperbolic and degenerate equilibrium points?

I do have the book by Perko, *Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems, 3rd ED*. So if it is actually in there, and I just cannot find me, it would be great if someone could point me to the respective part of the book as well!

Thanks for help!

Comment: It seldom happens that you have the same asymptotics for **all** points in the domain of attraction of the equilibrium. Even in the linear case, some points approach the origin faster than other, see, e.g., the discussion below [eigenvalues negative realparts one zero eigenvalue convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2694375/eigenvalues-negative-realparts-one-zero-eigenvalue-convergence#comment5565453_2694375).

Comment: This is interesting! Just to make sure I read you correctly: You are saying that the lowest order term decaying with $t$ in such an expansion would generally depend on the initial value $\mathbf x(t_0)$, correct? I do not doubt you, but it is confusing me right now, since I am dealing with a problem in mathematical physics, similar to what has been done in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0005116.pdf. On the bottom of p. 10 the authors make a statement that such an expansion can always be made, and then on the beginning of the next page give an example. I must be missing something!

Comment: Curiously enough, the example of a critical point in $\mathbb R^2$ with one eigenvalue exactly zero, and the other one negative is exactly the case I am looking at right now. The solutions of interest are attracted to the point along the centre manifold. I tried to follow the discussion in the other thread you linked, but I cannot see how this tells me that different solutions approach the point with different rate. Could I just try it out for my specific system at hand? If yes, how would I do so? Simply linearise the system at the fixed point?

Comment: The concrete system I am looking at right now is this one by the way: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149210/stability-of-non-hyperbolic-critical-point-in-two-dimensions-where-the-lineariz?rq=1

Comment: The overall picture is the following: the points lying on the invariant manifold $M_1$ tangent to the eigenvector with the eigenvalue with the smallest real part $\lambda_1$ converge as fast as $e^{\lambda_1 t}$, those lying on the invariant manifold $M_2$ tangent to the eigenvector with the eigenvalue with the second smallest real part $\lambda_2$, except those in $M_1$, converge as fast as $e^{\lambda_2 t}$, etc.  So, the "majority" of point converge to the equilibrium converge to the equilibrium as slow as possible.

Comment: The properties described in my earlier comment follow from the theory of (local) invariant manifolds, in particular, from their characterization: they are precisely the sets of points having a prescribed rate of decay.  For example, on the center manifold they cannot decay as fast as $e^{-\epsilon t}$, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Indeed, when the equilibrium is asymptotically stable and its linearization has one zero and one negative eigenvalue, then all the points close to the equilibrium, except those belonging to the (necessarily unique) stable manifold, tend to the equilibrium as slow as possible.  Moreover, there is a *unique asymptotic phase*: for each point close to the equilbrium there is a unique point on a center manifold such that their orbits approach each other at a logarithmic rate roughly equal to the negative eigenvalue.

Comment: `"they are precisely the sets of points having a prescribed rate of decay"` Does that imply that in general for points which do not lie on any of the invariant manifolds, I cannot really tell how fast they will converge? The critical point I am dealing with right now is a saddle-node: one region resembles a saddle and one region resembles a stable node. The stable manifold acts as a separatrix between those two regions. It is the stable-node region I am interested in. 1/2

Comment: So if I read you correctly, the statements of stable- and centre manifold theory should allow me to give convergence rates for points on those manifolds, but not for points which do not lie on either of those, correct? 2/2

Comment: I found the relevant statement concerning the convergence rates for stable and unstable manifolds in the book of Perko, but I could not yet find the relevant statement for the centre manifold case. Could you point me to a source where I can read up on that by any chance? Thanks a lot for being so helpful by the way!

Comment: When I need a reference I am usually using Hirsch & Pugh & Shub [Invariant Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0092042). Perhaps that would be an overkill in your case, but it gives results on the hierarchy of pseudo-stable, pseudo-unstable, etc., manifolds (and gives the characterization I was alluding to).  Also, the book is for discrete time only, but that should not be an obstacle.

Comment: It seems like we do have that in the library. I will check it out, thank you! As a last question, may I ask you to please briefly comment on my previous two replies?

Comment: In a nutshell: for any point close to the equilibrium the rate of convergence is equal to the real part of some eigenvalue; to which eigenvalue, it depends on the invariant manifold on which the point does lie.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And if the point doesn't lie on an invariant manifold, I will not be able to estimate the convergence rate in general, correct?

Comment: No, not correct: you always be able to estimate (see the book by Hirsch, Pugh and Shub I referred to).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Picked the book up today, and studying.